# ubuntu 16.04 - Slow after sometime and freezes

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu slow and freeze after sometime. I think it's some partition problem. I just post the `fdisk -l` result here.

```
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048    999423    997376   487M 82 Linux swap /   Solaris
/dev/sda2        1001470 625141759 624140290 297.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        1001472  40060927  39059456  18.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       40062976  79122431  39059456  18.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       79124480 625141759 546017280 260.4G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to give this memory partition : (May solve your problem ) your /dev/sda1 is comparatively small

```
/dev/sda1  *         2048   7813119   7811072   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sda2         7815166 488396799 480581634 229.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       307857408 410271743 102414336  48.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       410273792 488396799  78123008  37.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7         7815168 307857407 300042240 143.1G 83 Linux
```

Check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) why Linux swap should be >1G

Comment: Try to partition , so that Linux swap can get enough larger space for better performance.