# Ubuntu hangs in my laptop

Tags: 16.04

My laptop is INSPIRON 1545 with the following configurations

- 2GB ram
- 250GB hard disk
- Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6400 @ 2.00GHz × 2

I installed ubuntu 16.04 last month but it was quite laggy on my laptop. I really want to use use it. i am currently using solus which is good but is there a way to use ubuntu on my laptop without it lagging?

Comment: Have you installed a graphic driver? This could cause the slowness/laggyness of your system if you haven't so far.

Comment: And what do you mean with 'using solus'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance) and possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: What's your graphics adapter? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`?

Answer (score 0):

(1)First of all make clean your tmp folder :

```
find /tmp -ctime +5 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

(This will delete your files older than 5 days)

(2) Try to use [logrotate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10) to maintain your log files .

(3) Increase your RAM , if it is possible.

(4) Try to make partition such that linux swap partition can get enough large memory for swaping purpose , it will not allow to hang your laptop .[Read](https://askubuntu.com/a/819901/569952) my answer.

Comment: I think his HD2000 graphics processor may be more at issue (ie i915 driver loaded?) than temp files...

Comment: There may be more than one reason for that